# Space between li items

Tags: css, iscroll

I am trying to create a scrollable horizontal list using iscroll. The list seems to work pretty fine. The problem i am facing is that, there is some space between each li items. I tried everything i know. But i just cant remove the space between those li items.
Please check the demo below
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/uzucev/1/edit)

Comment: You just need to remove all whitespace between your `</li>` and `<li>` tags when using `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove  `display: inline-block;` and use  `float:left;`

```
#scroller li {
    background: #f7f7f7; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.1, #D8D3D3), color-stop(0.5, #FBFBFB) ); 
    float:left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    border:none;
    margin:0px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/uzucev/6/edit

Hope this will help

Comment: it works, but could you tell me why `display: inline-block;` create a gap between `li` tags?

Answer (score 0):

Add display:table-cell property to your css

```
#scroller li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
border: medium none;
display: table-cell;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
width: 120px;
```

}

I hope it will work for you.